# Create Json file from paths provided in a file

Tags: python, shell

For one of our environment, we have an automation crontab tool that produces the result in a file in the following format

As you can see that directories are "0" size and files have a size associated.
I am in need for a script that read this file and produces a JSON output.
However, the directory sizes need to be calculated based on all the files in its hierarchy.

File output

```
drwxrwxr-x  -    user1       root 1398089926561          0 /user
drwxrwxr-x  -    user1       root 1398089926561          0 /user/user1
drwxr-xr-x  -    user1       root 1398089926586          0 /user/user1/dir1
-rwxr-xr-x  1    user1       root 1398089926972        200 /user/user1/dir1/file1.csv
-rwxr-xr-x  1    user1       root 1398089927009        300 /user/user1/dir1/file2.tsv
drwxr-xr-x  -    user1       root 1398089929786          0 /user/user1/temp/lib
-rwxr-xr-x  1    user1       root 1398089927077         50 /user/user1/temp/lib/file5.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1    user1       root 1398089927139        600 /user/user1/temp/lib/file.jar
drwxr-xr-x  -     root       root 1398089829218          0 /app
drwxr-xr-x  -     root       root 1398089829218          0 /app/panther
drwxrwxrwx  -    N1234       root 1398176496064          0 /app/panther/warehouse/warehouse
drwxr-xr-x  -      E56       root 1398176493177          0 /app/panther/warehouse/warehouse/sample_07
-rw-r--r--  1      E56       root 1398176493340         50 /app/panther/warehouse/warehouse/sample_07/sample_07.csv
drwxr-xr-x  -      E56       root 1398176495945          0 /app/panther/warehouse/warehouse/sample_08
-rw-r--r--  1      E56       root 1398176495981        250 /app/panther/warehouse/warehouse/sample_08/sample_08.csv
```

and the output should look like following

{

```
"name":"Total",
"size":1450,
"children":[
    {
        "name":"user",
        "size":1150,
        "children":[
            {
                "name":"user1",
                "size":1150,
                "children":[
                    {
                        "name":"dir1",
                        "size":500,
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "name":"file1.csv",
                                "size":200
                            },
                            {
                                "name":"file2.tsv",
                                "size":300
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name":"temp",
                        "size":650,
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "name":"lib",
                                "size":650,
                                "children":[
                                    {
                                        "name":"file5.txt",
                                        "size":50
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name":"file.jar",
                                        "size":600
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"app",
        "size":300,
        "children":[
            {
                "name":"panther",
                "size":300,
                "children":[
                    {
                        "name":"warehouse",
                        "size":300,
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "name":"sample_07",
                                "size":50,
                                "children":[
                                    {
                                        "name":"sample_07.csv",
                                        "size":50
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name":"sample_08",
                                "size":250,
                                "children":[
                                    {
                                        "name":"sample_08.csv",
                                        "size":250
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

As you can see the directories are spread out hierarchically and display the aggregated directory size.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: read `man du` (especially the `-s` switch) and use shell `for` loops

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tree` command. Note that it is a shell command, and to get json output you will have to add the `-J` flag.

To do this from withing `python` use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['tree', '-J'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, The directory structure above is in file and its a  large cluster (over 1000 nodes). the stats above are being pulled from multiple hosts and get scp over to one of our proxy server. At

Comment: If it works for you can you [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Answer (score 0):

Your structure makes it very difficult to determine if you have already seen a particular directory, if instead you chose children to be a dictionary of name to attributes (children, size). Then you can implement a pseudo recursive tree construction with a recurse tree summer.

**Code**:

```
root = {}
for line in s:
    size, p = line[48:].lstrip().split(' ')
    path = p[1:].split('/')
    o = root
    for i in path:
        o = o.setdefault('children', {})
        o = o.setdefault(i, {})
    o['size'] = int(size)

def sumtree(d):
    if 'children' not in d:
        return d['size']
    d.setdefault('size', 0)
    for c in d['children'].values():
        d['size'] += sumtree(c)
    return d['size']

print("Total: {}".format(sumtree(root)))
print(root)
```

**Ouput**:

```
Total: 1450
{
    'children': {
        'app': {
            'children': {
                'panther': {
                    'children': {
                        'warehouse': {
                            'children': {
                                'warehouse': {
                                    'children': {
                                        'sample_07': {
                                            'children': {
                                                'sample_07.csv': {'size': 50}
                                            },
                                            'size': 50},
                                        'sample_08': {
                                            'children': {
                                                'sample_08.csv': {'size': 250}
                                            },
                                            'size': 250}},
                                    'size': 300}},
                            'size': 300}},
                    'size': 300}},
            'size': 300},
        'user': {
            'children': {
                'user1': {
                    'children': {
                        'dir1': {
                            'children': {
                                'file1.csv': {'size': 200},
                                'file2.tsv': {'size': 300}
                            },
                            'size': 500
                        },
                        'temp': {
                            'children': {
                                'lib': {
                                    'children': {
                                        'file.jar': {'size': 600},
                                        'file5.txt': {'size': 50}
                                    },
                                    'size': 650}},
                            'size': 650}},
                    'size': 1150}},
            'size': 1150}},
    'size': 1450
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant with `du --all`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import os
import subprocess
import json

root_dir = '/path/to/your/dir'
out_filename = '/tmp/out.json'

output = subprocess.check_output(['du', '--all', root_dir])
lines = output.splitlines()
lookup_table = {}

for line in lines:
    size, filepath = line.split('\t', 1)

    _tmp = lookup_table.setdefault(filepath, {})
    _tmp.update({
        'name': os.path.basename(filepath),
        'size': size
    })

    dirpath = os.path.dirname(filepath)
    (lookup_table
        .setdefault(dirpath, {})
        .setdefault('children', [])
        .append(_tmp))

with open(out_filename, 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(lookup_table[root_dir], fh)
```